# Mercurial - how to get rid of additional default heads

Tags: mercurial

I am on the default branch, but some old commits are said by mercurial to be other default heads.
I would like to push a commit, but I can't because otherwise I would have to push other default heads which would be wrong.

How can I make the situation clean? I assume I have to get reed of these additional default heads and so that I again push my work. Is there a safe way to do it?

Comment: Use `hg heads -r .` to review the set of heads for the current branch, then figure out *why* you have extra heads. A head is simply a commit with no descendants (in the same branch, or at all, depends on `hg heads --topo` flag). Why do you have these commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First piece of advice is to backup you repo so that if something goes wrong, you have a return path.

You will need to determine if the other heads are important or if they can be thrown away. You can list the heads with:

```
hg heads
```

if the other heads are throwaways, you can use the hg strip command. Some caution is
needed here. If you created a anonymous branch (the head in question) and later merged
it back to your default (or other branch), deleting it will cause any changed after the merge to also be removed.

You should spend some time reviewing: hg log -G (or one of the many graphical interfaces) and determine if this is going to be an issue.

If it is an orphan branch (head) you can use:

```
hg strip changeset-id
```

Comment: Hopefully I kept the situation clean, so hg strip just removed the revisions 1 by 1. You just have to be careful because each time the revision number are updated so that there is no gap.

Comment: Use hashes, they are unique as opposed to the numeric IDs.

Comment: Important clarification: a changeset can be a head on one branch and yet have descendants on other (named) branches. Hence the risk of using strip. I think this is implied in this answer but newer hg users may not realize that.

Comment: This is very true and important to consider. Use of hg log -G or another graphical log viewer can really help you see this.